# URLLIB Syntax Error

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

For the last three months, I have been running every day a program that downloads a picture from a remote site. Now all of the sudden the instruction that opens the JPG picture file gives me an error

```
urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.giglionews.com/isoladelgiglio_porto.jpg')
```

after a bunch of tracebacks

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I have not changed anything in my program, and I'm wondering to what it could be related, and how to fix it. I'm running Python 3.3.2 in Windows 8.
I do import urllib.request at the beginning of the program, and I'm wondering if it is possible that the library got corrupted.

Comment: I don't see how that code could ever have worked.  You need some kind of quote around a string literal, like `urlopen("http://example.com")` or `urlopen('http://example.com')`.

Comment: You are right. I copied the line from the program incorrectly. I'm correcting my question.

Comment: DSM, could you please take a look again, now that I have restated the issue?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't use Windows, but that error message makes it seem like the change isn't on your code's side.

Comment: As @DSM stated, it is probably not `urllib` or your code. It is most likely that the website maintainer shut down the website to crawlers. Try switching your user-agent or something similar.